# How to escape backslash in json object key

Tags: json

I want to reference this json key : `Added Date/Time`

```
{{ contact.["Added Date\\Time"] }}
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include a literal double quote in a JSON string, you must escape it by preceding it with a backslash . So your JSON string would have to look like this:
`{"key" : " \"Some text WITH quotes\" "}`

See [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for the official JSON syntax.

The forward slash / is not a special character and does not need to be escaped. The backslash \ needs to be escaped with itself: \\.

Answer (score 1):

Because the string literal does not match the required key. You need to ensure that the string literal in your source code matches the actual JSON key.

In most languages, this character sequence will do it: `Added Date/Time`. (there is no escaping required).

Note, this string is NOT a JSON string - it's a string literal in your programming language. Thus, this string must obey the escaping rules of your current programming language, not the rules of JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I just found chirag's answer a bit more complete.

Comment: @ManosPapoutsakis Understanding JSON and reading the specification is really mandatory and useful when doing programming tasks like yours. However, you need also to understand that you don't deal with JSON-Strings in your code sample. So, while chirag's answer is useful it's not relevant to your problem, but the escaping rules for string literals in your _programming language_ are crucial for your problem.